# How to capture Alt + Tab

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I want change `ItemSource` or something when pressing the `Alt + Tab` so how to do this. I have tried below the code but its not work in WPF:

```
void MainWindow_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Tab && (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Alt) == ModifierKeys.Alt)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("CTRL + TAB trapped");
    }    
}
```

Comment: Are you able to consider a different key combination? You really shouldn't override system commands for a context sensitive operations. The user should never have to ask 'why doesn't this work'.

Answer (score 3):

You need to hook into the Windows API to get access to the keyboard and intercept these calls. Check out the guidance given [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14485/Low-level-Windows-API-hooks-from-C-to-stop-unwante)